# Select Dropdown menu value from buttons on form submission Approve / Reject

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to work out how I can have two submit buttons, one approve and one reject.  When selecting 'Approve', it will change the approved dropdown to 'Yes', or 'No' for reject.  There are other select menus on my form, so I need it specific to this dropdown.  I have been trying to edit a few different examples of JQuery and Javascript solutions but am no where near getting this right.  Heres my work http://jsfiddle.net/nbren007/cxokhr7e/1/ so far.

```
<li><label for>Approved</label>

<select class="selectMenu" ID="_1_1_116_1" NAME="_1_1_116_1" /required>
<option value="" >&lt;None&gt;</option>
<option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
<option value="No" >No</option>
</select>
</li>

<INPUT CLASS="applyButton" TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Approve">
<INPUT CLASS="applyButton" TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Reject">
```

Comment: Firstly, change `/required` to `required`. Secondly why are you trying to use submit buttons to change a dropdown selection?

Comment: And using capital letters in an uncommon practice in html...

Comment: Two submit buttons as it performs a part of my workflow.  If the value is 'Yes' then it's approved and something else happens, if it's rejected it will go back to another step.  I intend to hide the drop down from users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".applyButton").click(function(){
  $('#1_1_116_1').val("Yes");
});
$(".resetButton").click(function(){
  $('#1_1_116_1').val("No");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/cxokhr7e/5/)

*Side note: `submit` or `reset` buttons works inside a `<form>`. you can use a simple button for this functionality. Also, `<li>` should be inside a `<ul>`*

Comment: It works great, but it shouldn't be a reset button, it needs to be two apply buttons, as they should both submit the form.  The value of the selected dropdown determines something else later on.  Therefore would I need the input buttons to have an IDs so they can change the values?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
<button CLASS="applyButton btn" VALUE="Yes">apply</button>
<button CLASS="resetButton btn" VALUE="No">reset</button>

$('.btn').click(function(){     
    $('#_1_1_116_1').val($(this).attr("value"));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cxokhr7e/4/